# Reorder compile tasks in gradle's build task

Tags: java, groovy, clojure, build-process, gradle

I am trying to build my project that has some java source and clojure source code, in a directory structure like the following:

```
src
`-- main
    |-- clojure
    |   `-- appc
    |       `-- core.clj
    `-- java
        `-- appj
            `-- AppStarter.java
```

I have loaded the `java`, `clojure` and `application` plugins in my gradle build file. Clojure plugin is from https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/clojuresque/overview, version *1.5.2*.

Here, the clojure code, `core.clj`, has code that uses the classes written in java. But there is nothing in the java source that depends on the clojure code.

Now, when I do `gradle tasks --all`, I see

```
...
classes - Assembles the main classes.
    compileClojure - Compile the main Clojure source.
    compileJava - Compiles the main Java source.
    processResources - Processes the main resources.
...
```

So, the `build` task will compile my clojure sources first and then the java sources. This obviously doesn't work, because the clojure code depends on the java part. So I need `compileJava` to happen before `compileClojure`.

Changing the order of applying the `clojure` and `java` plugins didn't have any effect.

Since the clojure plugin is new, I tried out with the `groovy` and `scala` plugins. I got the following in each case.

```
...
classes - Assembles the main classes.
    compileGroovy - Compile the main Groovy source.
    compileJava - Compiles the main Java source.
    processResources - Processes the main resources.
...
```

and

```
...
classes - Assembles the main classes.
    compileJava - Compiles the main Java source.
    compileScala - Compile the main Scala source.
    processResources - Processes the main resources.
...
```

I suppose there should be a way to reorder these right? I couldn't find out in the docs (despite them being *really* good!). Is there any way to tell gradle to compile my java sources build first, and then compile the clojure sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the order right is as simple as `compileClojure.dependsOn(compileJava)`. The other question is if the Java classes are correctly placed on the Clojure compiler's class path.

PS: The order of tasks in the `gradle tasks` output says nothing about the order in which the tasks execute. Order of task execution is entirely determined by task dependencies.

Comment: You're right! After adding that line, gradle behaves the way I want it to, but the order in `tasks --all` did not change. I was trying `build.dependsOn compileJava`. Oh well. Thank you very much, it works now.

Comment: The output of the java compiler should be correctly placed on the classpath for the clojure compile task. I did not depend on the java compilation since it is a priori not clear which way is the "correct" one. Just as well the java source could depend on a class generated by the clojure part. So the user has to explicitly specify what he wants.